# Random page in pdf output

Tags: pdftex, page-breaking

For some reason I got this page after compiling my document today,
[image: Weird Latex page for no reason]

The log file shows this around the place where it occurs:

```
    Underfull \hbox (badness 3482) in paragraph at lines 1685--1685
\T1/mdugm/m/n/10 lated from pre-cip-itable
 []

[29]
Overfull \hbox (9.82391pt too wide) in paragraph at lines 1783--1788
 [][] 
 []

) (../5aims&objectives/aims&objectives.tex [30]) [31]
(../4data&methods/data&methods.tex [32]
Chapter 2.
<../figures/StudyArea.png, id=2314, 647.2983pt x 504.2037pt>
File: ../figures/StudyArea.png Graphic file (type png)
<use ../figures/StudyArea.png>
Package pdftex.def Info: ../figures/StudyArea.png  used on input line 57. on in
put line 57.
Package pdftex.def Info: Requested size: 455.24411pt x 354.60968pt on input lin
e 57.
```

Specifically before you see **chapter2** ^ . Here is my preamble, I don't think the problem is in it though.

It's between the end of a section and a new chapter, if that helps.

Comment: the log doesn't show anything about page 32, it presumably could only fit in that last line, then you have a forced break for the start of the following chapter,

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Does `hyperref` need loading before `glossaries` as the OP has it?

Comment: Wait what.. When should I load hyperref? It works perfectly, so why bother?

Answer (score 2):

I feel like an idiot.

I use headings like this in my document to name things;

```
%---------------------
%SectionName
%---------------------
```

this happened;

```
l---------------------
%SectionName
%---------------------
```

Problem fixed by correcting that. I can't believe I missed that.